# Issues loading bazel rule from remote achieve

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, bazel

So I am trying to learn Bazel by setting up a barebones spring project. Newest spring boot 5 uses JUnit5. Bazel only natively runs JUnit 4. I find this repo https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_jvm that has a drop in replacement for "java_test" it. I believe I set it up as the repo describes...

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "contrib_rules_jvm",
    sha256 = "59af045d288ad3e2d9000b1cddb1135f889d798830f7106a4792cc95427bcd99",
    strip_prefix = "rules_jvm-0.7.0",
    url = "https://github.com/bazel-contrib/rules_jvm/archive/refs/tags/v0.7.0.zip",
)

# Fetches the contrib_rules_jvm dependencies.
# If you want to have a different version of some dependency,
# you should fetch it *before* calling this.
load("@contrib_rules_jvm//:repositories.bzl", "contrib_rules_jvm_deps")

contrib_rules_jvm_deps()

# Now ensure that the downloaded deps are properly configured
load("@contrib_rules_jvm//:setup.bzl", "contrib_rules_jvm_setup")

contrib_rules_jvm_setup()
```

Adding this to my WORKSPACE file. As the top of the README says, and the lease page specifies. But when I attempt to use the new rule `

```
java_junit5_test()
```

It say it is not defined. Is there some special thing you need to do to reload a WORKSPACE file? I am using intelliJ with the bazel plugin. I also have the "maven_install" stuff all setup and working in the WORKSPACE file and it's pulling those packages just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Was missing

`load("@contrib_rules_jvm//java:defs.bzl", "java_junit5_test")`

in my BUILD file.